# Compare PHP var with AngularJS var

Tags: php, angularjs

in this code:

```
<?php
    //students.name in js = "JUANITO"
    $value = "{{ students.name }}";
    $name  = "JUANITO";
    if($value==$name) echo "EQUALS";
    else echo "DIFFERENT";
?>
```

the result is: "DIFFERENT" .. Why?

Comment: The ""{{ students.name }}" makes me think this is javascript code. You cannot use javascript code and variables directly in PHP like that.

You can however send the variable in JS to a PHP script (e.g. with a form or AJAX) and compare it there.

It's literally comparing the string `{{ students.name }}` to `JUANITO` which is, indeed, different.

Comment: First of all, why would you want to compare Angular variable to PHP variable? Second, PHP renders before Angular's run, therefore this will not work and $value will not be assigned as you'd expect.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer!
But... if :
<?php
   echo $value." ".$name;
?>
show: "JUANITO JUANITO"

Comment: php echo `{{ students.name }} JUANITO`, then Angular replace `{{ students.name }}` with `JUANITO` and you read `JUANITO JUANITO`. Instead of echoing it, try to save it to a local file and you will see the real php output. `{{something}}` is a common placeholder syntax, adopted also by angular.

Comment: @fusion3k very good point!

Comment: Very thanks!
Thanks to all!
( @fusion3k very very very good point! )